# How does ParentBackground work on IDE generated Forms?

Tags: delphi, tform

This code works fine with an IDE generated form in a VCL Forms Application:

```
Self.ParentBackground := True;
```

But why? None of the ascendants (`TForm`, `TCustomForm`, `TScrollingWinControl`) publish the protected `ParentBackground` property of `TWinControl`. The type declaration for the form (f.i. 'TForm1') at the top of the unit, does not either. Indeed, as expected, this

```
TForm(Self).ParentBackground := True;
```

does not compile (*"Cannot access protected symbol TWinControl.ParentBackground"*). Same with any form created at runtime.

**Note**: The question is **not** about how can I set the property (BTW, there are others, like 'Bevel[xxx]'), I'd like to know how does this work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Self.ParentBackground := True;
```

compiles because a class can access its own protected members.

Answer (score 4):

But `TForm1(Self).ParentBackground` works. The difference is that the class `TForm1` (which `Self` belongs to) is declared in the same unit; then you can indeed access protected members.

Comment: No, that's not it. It's not which unit the code is declared in that matters. At least not the reason why Self.XXX compiles.

Comment: Well, @David, this does indeed matter. But in this case, you are right.

Comment: Yeah, it matters for TForm1(...).XXX but I think that's a little off to the side of Sertac's question, as I read it.

Comment: Try `initialization Form1.ParentBackground := true;` in `Unit1` and `Unit2`. It will only compile in the first case (of course it will crash, but still).

Comment: You are right. Still, I think I'll leave my answer here, because a natural follow-up question is "in what other cases can you access the protected members of a class"?

Comment: OK, good point. That's a nuance that I was not aware of. It feels a little weird to me. I wonder what's the rationale.

Comment: I guess protected does not mean "accessible to the class and its descendants". It means "accessible in the units that declare the class and its descendants".

Comment: Thank you for the answer Andreas, I think David's answer address my question a little bit more directly.

Comment: The documentation states: "A protected member is visible anywhere in the module where its class is declared and from any descendent class,
regardless of the module where the descendent class
appears." I think that is misleading. It should read "A protected member is visible anywhere in the module where its class is declared and anywhere in any module which declares a descendent class."